# Update with select

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update

I have the following tables:

`TARIF_COURANT`

```
CODE_TARIF   NO_CLIENT   ZONE  UNITE
  A_0_300       8585      1      8
  A_0_300       8585      1      5
```

`T_TARIF_ZONE`

```
NO_ID   LIBELLE
  1       A
  2       B
```

`T_UNITE`

```
NO_ID   LIBELLE
  8       MOT
  5       FUT
```

How can I `Update` my table `TARIF_COURANT` to get this result:

```
 CODE_TARIF     NO_CLIENT   ZONE   UNITE
 A-MOT_0_300       8585      1       8
 A-FUT_0_300       8585      1       5
```

i have tried like this:

```
UPDATE
    TARIF_COURANT
SET
    TARIF_COURANT.CODE_TARIF =  T_TARIF_ZONE.LIBELLE +'-'
       + RTRIM(LTRIM( T_UNITE.LIBELLE) )+'_'
       +CONVERT(varchar, [TR_DEB]) 
       +'_'+CONVERT(varchar, [TR_FIN])
FROM
    TARIF_COURANT
     left join T_UNITE on TARIF_COURANT.unite = T_UNITE.NO_ID
     left join T_TARIF_ZONE on TARIF_COURANT.zone = T_TARIF_ZONE.NO_ID
      where no_client = '850673' and unite != 1
ON
    TARIF_COURANT.CODE_TARIF = TARIF_COURANT.CODE_TARIF
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Post some working queries, does not matter if the result is incorrect, is a starting point and maybe you are not far from the solution. And also wich is your RDBMS: MySQL, MS SQL Server, Postgresql, oracle?

Comment: I think we're all missing the point here. Nobody has bothered asking what they've tried.

Comment: In all seriousness, really? The person has 12 rep, cut them some slack.

Comment: Your last `ON
    TARIF_COURANT.CODE_TARIF = TARIF_COURANT.CODE_TARIF` is syntactically wrong. Remove it and see if it works then.

Comment: @user1958628 I added my comment as answer so you can accept it to "close" this question. Or was it not my comment which helped?

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE t
SET t.CODE_TARIF = ttz.LIBELLE 
  + '-' + RTRIM(LTRIM( tu.LIBELLE) )
  + '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), [TR_DEB]) -- what table does this come from? 
  + '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), [TR_FIN]) -- what table does this come from?
--------------------------^^ don't be lazy! Specify a length!
FROM
  dbo.TARIF_COURANT AS t -- use aliases and proper schema prefixes
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  dbo.t_UNITE AS tu
  ON t.unite = tu.NO_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  dbo.T_TARIF_ZONE AS ttz
  ON t.zone = ttz.NO_ID
WHERE
  no_client = '850673' -- what table does this come from?
  and unite <> 1;      -- what table does this come from?
```